# Open a file from a URL in OS X

Tags: macos, eclipse, text-editors

Many applications (Eclipse, TextMate, ...) use OS X's integrated *Open File…* dialog where you have to browse and select the file and then click *Open*. I have many directories with many files. So opening the file can take even 20 seconds.

However I have the URL from the terminal. Given this URL of the file in the buffer, how can I use it to open the file **quickly** in a standard way? Is that even possible? One would expect that putting the URL in the search box would work, but it does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably mean a *path* (`/Users/danielbeck/Desktop/file.txt`) and not a *URL* (`file:///Users/danielbeck/Desktop/file.txt`) if you get it from Terminal.

If so, you can press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> in the file dialog of the program you want to open the file with, paste the path, and the file will get selected. Just confirm the selection and the file will be opened.

---

Alternatively, you can use the `open` command in Terminal to open it in the default program:

```
open /Users/danielbeck/Desktop/file.txt
```

Or in a specific program, e.g. *Sublime Text 2*:

```
open -a 'Sublime Text 2' /Users/danielbeck/Desktop/file.txt
```

This approach also supports `file://` URLs.

<sup>(This will probably not work with Eclipse)</sup>

Comment: As an alternative to commencing with `file:///` (triple forw slash), you could also `file://host/` + `path`.
[Source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252371989)